# How to get <td> tags by specific attribute's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have cells presented with `<td>` tags.
Every cell has row and column number.
Example for syntax of cell with `row = 0` and `col = 0`:

```
<td class row="0" col="0">
<span>1</span>
</td>
```

I want to get the  tags according to specific attribute's value.
For example, I want to get the first cell which has: row = 0 and col = 0
I tried:

```
$("td").attr("row", 0).attr("col", 0)
```

but its overwrite the values of the attributes:
[image]

How can I get  tags according to specific attribute's value? (I prefer with jQuery)

Comment: $("td[row=0][col=0]")

Comment: Don't make up random attributes, use custom data attributes instead. Ex: `data-row="1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above. But to do what you're asking in jQuery, use:

```
$('td[row="0"][col="2"]').html()
```

Answer (score 2):

In [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com/), you could use [`node.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) or [`node.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) with a [selector which matches these attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), for example

```
function getTds(row, col) { // NodeList
    return document.querySelectorAll('td[row="' + row + '"][col="' + col + '"]');
}
```

Then for *row 4 col 0*

```
var td = getTds(4, 0)[0]; // HTMLTableCellElement or undefined
```

Comment: _row_ and _col_ are non-standard so I didn't want to assume these will be unique